# CMake/ninja error: '**/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio', needed by 'Release/addon.node', missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, core-audio, ninja

**Description:**
I am working on a C++ project using CMake to build a Node.js addon that relies on several dependencies, including the CoreAudio framework.I encounter an issue on macOS when trying to build the project using CMake and ninja. The error message is as follows:

```
ninja: error: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio', needed by 'Release/addon.node', missing and no known rule to make it.
```

I have verified that the CoreAudio framework is present on my system, and I have set the correct path in the CMakeLists.txt file. However, the build system seems unable to locate the framework during the build process.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project (addon)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")

set(mediasuite_home .)
get_filename_component(MEDIASUITE_ABSOLUTE_PATH ${mediasuite_home} ABSOLUTE)

if(APPLE)
    set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${MEDIASUITE_ABSOLUTE_PATH}/deps/ffmpeg/macosx/lib/pkgconfig")
elseif(UNIX)
    set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${MEDIASUITE_ABSOLUTE_PATH}/deps/ffmpeg/linux/lib/pkgconfig")
elseif(WIN32)
    set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${MEDIASUITE_ABSOLUTE_PATH}/deps/ffmpeg/windows/lib/pkgconfig")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported operating system")
endif()

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFORMAT   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL     REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavfilter)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE   REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(SWRESAMPLE REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswscale)

include_directories(${CMAKE_JS_INC})
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${CMAKE_JS_SRC})

if(APPLE)
        find_library(CORE_AUDIO CoreAudio REQUIRED)
        if(NOT CORE_AUDIO)
                message(FATAL_ERROR "CoreAudio framework not found")
        else()
                message(STATUS "CoreAudio framework found: ${CORE_AUDIO}")
        endif()
        find_library(CORE_MEDIA CoreMedia REQUIRED)
        find_library(VIDEO_TOOLBOX VideoToolBox REQUIRED)
        find_library(AUDIO_TOOLBOX AudioToolBox REQUIRED)
        find_library(CORE_FOUNDATION CoreFoundation REQUIRED)
        find_library(SECURITY Security REQUIRED)
        find_library(CORE_SERVICES CoreServices REQUIRED)
        set(
                frameworks
                ${CORE_AUDIO}/CoreAudio
                ${CORE_MEDIA}/CoreMedia
                ${VIDEO_TOOLBOX}/VideoToolbox
                ${AUDIO_TOOLBOX}/AudioToolbox
                ${CORE_FOUNDATION}/CoreFoundation
                ${SECURITY}/Security
                ${CORE_SERVICES}/CoreServices
        )
elseif(UNIX)
        message(STATUS "UNIX OPERATING SYSTEM CONFIG")
elseif(WIN32)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM CONFIG")
else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported operating system")
endif()

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".node")
target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} 
        ${CMAKE_JS_LIB}
        ${AVCODEC_LDFLAGS} 
        ${AVFORMAT_LDFLAGS} 
        ${AVFILTER_LDFLAGS} 
        ${AVDEVICE_LDFLAGS} 
        ${AVUTIL_LDFLAGS}
        ${SWRESAMPLE_LDFLAGS} 
        ${SWSCALE_LDFLAGS}
        ${frameworks}
)
execute_process(COMMAND node -p "require('node-addon-api').include"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE NODE_ADDON_API_DIR
        )

string(REPLACE "\n" "" NODE_ADDON_API_DIR ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})
string(REPLACE "\"" "" NODE_ADDON_API_DIR ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})

target_include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
        ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR}
        ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
        ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
        ${AVFILTER_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
        ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
        ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
        ${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
        ${SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_definitions(-DNAPI_VERSION=3)
```

I also tried
 `"-framework CoreAudio" and ${CORE_AUDIO}`

I got

```
-- CoreAudio framework found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework
-- Configuring done (0.9s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/vetagirihrushikesh/Desktop/Maigha/CoreProducts/Development/FFMPEG_BUILD/BuildScriptForMacOSX/ElectronReactBoilerPlate/FFMPEGNAPIELECTRON/Nodejs-Napi-Addon-Using-Cmake/build
info CMD BUILD
info RUN cmake --build "/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/Desktop/Maigha/CoreProducts/Development/FFMPEG_BUILD/BuildScriptForMacOSX/ElectronReactBoilerPlate/FFMPEGNAPIELECTRON/Nodejs-Napi-Addon-Using-Cmake/build" --config Release
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library Release/addon.node
FAILED: Release/addon.node
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -g -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -o Release/addon.node -install_name @rpath/addon.node CMakeFiles/addon.dir/src/example.cpp.o  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lavcodec  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -liconv  -lm  -ldav1d  -framework  -lAudioToolbox  -lfdk-aac  -lmp3lame  -lm  -lopus  -lSvtAv1Enc  -lpthread  -lm  -lx264  -lpthread  -lm  -ldl  -lx265  -lc++  -ldl  -pthread  -lz  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -lswresample  -lm  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lavformat  -lm  -lbz2  -lz  -Wl,-framework,CoreFoundation  -Wl,-framework,Security  -lavcodec  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -liconv  -lm  -ldav1d  -framework  -lAudioToolbox  -lfdk-aac  -lmp3lame  -lm  -lopus  -lSvtAv1Enc  -lpthread  -lm  -lx264  -lpthread  -lm  -ldl  -lx265  -lc++  -ldl  -pthread  -lz  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -lswresample  -lm  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libass/0.17.1/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libunibreak/5.1/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/harfbuzz/8.3.0/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.78.1/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.42/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.14/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.13/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/freetype/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpng/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/freetype/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpng/lib  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lavfilter  -framework  -lOpenGL  -pthread  -lm  -lass  -liconv  -framework  -lApplicationServices  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -lunibreak  -lharfbuzz  -lm  -framework  -lApplicationServices  -lglib-2.0  -lintl  -liconv  -lm  -framework  -lFoundation  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lAppKit  -framework  -lCarbon  -lpcre2-8  -D_THREAD_SAFE  -pthread  -lgraphite2  -lfribidi  -lfreetype  -lbz2  -lpng16  -lz  -framework  -lMetal  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -framework  -lCoreImage  -framework  -lAppKit  -lfreetype  -lbz2  -lpng16  -lz  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -lswscale  -lm  -lpostproc  -lm  -lavformat  -lm  -lbz2  -lz  -Wl,-framework,CoreFoundation  -Wl,-framework,Security  -lavcodec  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -liconv  -lm  -ldav1d  -framework  -lAudioToolbox  -lfdk-aac  -lmp3lame  -lm  -lopus  -lSvtAv1Enc  -lpthread  -lm  -lx264  -lpthread  -lm  -ldl  -lx265  -lc++  -ldl  -pthread  -lz  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -lswresample  -lm  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/lib  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libass/0.17.1/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libunibreak/5.1/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/harfbuzz/8.3.0/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.78.1/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.42/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.14/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.13/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/freetype/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpng/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/freetype/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpng/lib  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lavdevice  -framework  -lFoundation  -framework  -lAudioToolbox  -framework  -lCoreAudio  -lm  -framework  -lAVFoundation  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreGraphics  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -lxcb-shm  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -lxcb-shape  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -lxcb-xfixes  -lxcb-render  -lxcb-shape  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lAudioToolbox  -pthread  -lSDL2  -lm  -liconv  -Wl,-framework,CoreAudio  -Wl,-framework,AudioToolbox  -Wl,-weak_framework,CoreHaptics  -Wl,-weak_framework,GameController  -Wl,-framework,ForceFeedback  -lobjc  -Wl,-framework,CoreVideo  -Wl,-framework,Cocoa  -Wl,-framework,Carbon  -Wl,-framework,IOKit  -Wl,-weak_framework,QuartzCore  -Wl,-weak_framework,Metal  -lavfilter  -framework  -lOpenGL  -pthread  -lm  -lass  -liconv  -framework  -lApplicationServices  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -lunibreak  -lharfbuzz  -lm  -framework  -lApplicationServices  -lglib-2.0  -lintl  -liconv  -lm  -framework  -lFoundation  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lAppKit  -framework  -lCarbon  -lpcre2-8  -D_THREAD_SAFE  -pthread  -lgraphite2  -lfribidi  -lfreetype  -lbz2  -lpng16  -lz  -framework  -lMetal  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -framework  -lCoreImage  -framework  -lAppKit  -lfreetype  -lbz2  -lpng16  -lz  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -lswscale  -lm  -lpostproc  -lm  -lavformat  -lm  -lbz2  -lz  -Wl,-framework,CoreFoundation  -Wl,-framework,Security  -lavcodec  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -lvpx  -lm  -lpthread  -liconv  -lm  -ldav1d  -framework  -lAudioToolbox  -lfdk-aac  -lmp3lame  -lm  -lopus  -lSvtAv1Enc  -lpthread  -lm  -lx264  -lpthread  -lm  -ldl  -lx265  -lc++  -ldl  -pthread  -lz  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -lswresample  -lm  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lswresample  -lm  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -L/Users/vetagirihrushikesh/ffmpeg_build/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.7/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.16/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/lib  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/lib  -lswscale  -lm  -lavutil  -pthread  -lm  -framework  -lVideoToolbox  -lX11  -lxcb  -lXau  -lXdmcp  -framework  -lCoreFoundation  -framework  -lCoreMedia  -framework  -lCoreVideo  -framework  -lCoreServices  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreAudio  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreMedia  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker VideoToolBox  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker AudioToolBox  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreFoundation  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker Security  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreServices  -lavdevice  -lCoreAudio  -lAVFoundation  -lCoreGraphics  -lxcb-shm  -lxcb-shape  -lxcb-xfixes  -lxcb-render  -lSDL2  -lobjc  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreAudio  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreMedia  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker VideoToolBox  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker AudioToolBox  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreFoundation  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker Security  -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker CoreServices && :
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lSDL2', '-lSvtAv1Enc', '-lX11', '-lXau', '-lXdmcp', '-lass', '-lavcodec', '-lavdevice', '-lavfilter', '-lavformat', '-lavutil', '-lbz2', '-lc++', '-ldav1d', '-ldl', '-lfdk-aac', '-lfreetype', '-lfribidi', '-lglib-2.0', '-lgraphite2', '-lharfbuzz', '-liconv', '-lintl', '-lm', '-lmp3lame', '-lobjc', '-lopus', '-lpcre2-8', '-lpng16', '-lpostproc', '-lpthread', '-lswresample', '-lswscale', '-lunibreak', '-lvpx', '-lx264', '-lx265', '-lxcb', '-lxcb-render', '-lxcb-shape', '-lxcb-shm', '-lxcb-xfixes', '-lz'
ld: library 'CoreAudio' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Result of `find_library` is a **complete path** which can be used in `target_link_libraries`. No needs to append subdirectory to that path, as you do in `${CORE_AUDIO}/CoreAudio`.

Answer (score 0):

This Cmake helped me.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project (multimagix)
set(PLATFORM "macosx")  # "macosx" "windows" "linux"
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
if(PLATFORM STREQUAL "linux")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -g -O3 -DNDEBUG")
endif()
set(mediasuite_home ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
get_filename_component(MEDIASUITE_ABSOLUTE_PATH ${mediasuite_home} ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(MULTIMAGIX_PATH ${mediasuite_home} ABSOLUTE)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_JS_INC}
        if(PLATFORM STREQUAL "macosx")
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/include
        elseif(PLATFORM STREQUAL "linux")
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/include
        endif()
)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp" "src/Conversion/*.cpp" "src/Resize/*.cpp" "src/Trim/*.cpp" "src/*.h" "src/Conversion/*.h" "src/Resize/*.h" "src/Trim/*.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${CMAKE_JS_SRC})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".node")

if(PLATFORM STREQUAL "macosx")
        find_library(CORE_AUDIO CoreAudio REQUIRED)
        find_library(CORE_MEDIA CoreMedia REQUIRED)
        find_library(VIDEO_TOOLBOX VideoToolBox REQUIRED)
        find_library(AUDIO_TOOLBOX AudioToolBox REQUIRED)
        find_library(CORE_FOUNDATION CoreFoundation REQUIRED)
        find_library(SECURITY Security REQUIRED)
        find_library(CORE_SERVICES CoreServices REQUIRED)
        target_link_libraries(
                ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                ${CMAKE_JS_LIB}
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libavcodec.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libavdevice.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libavfilter.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libavformat.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libavutil.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libdav1d.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libfdk-aac.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libmp3lame.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libopus.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libpostproc.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libSvtAv1Enc.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libswresample.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libswscale.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libvmaf.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libvpx.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libx264.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/macosx/lib/libx265.a
                ${CORE_AUDIO}
                ${CORE_MEDIA}
                ${VIDEO_TOOLBOX}
                ${AUDIO_TOOLBOX}
                ${CORE_FOUNDATION}
                ${SECURITY}
                ${CORE_SERVICES}
        )
elseif(PLATFORM STREQUAL "linux")
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                ${CMAKE_JS_LIB}
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libavcodec.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libavdevice.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libavfilter.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libavformat.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libavutil.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libpostproc.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libSvtAv1Enc.a
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libswresample.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libswscale.so
                ${MULTIMAGIX_PATH}/deps/FFMPEG/Ubuntu/lib/libvmaf.a
        )
endif()


execute_process(COMMAND node -p "require('node-addon-api').include"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE NODE_ADDON_API_DIR
        )

string(REPLACE "\n" "" NODE_ADDON_API_DIR ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})
string(REPLACE "\"" "" NODE_ADDON_API_DIR ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})

target_include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
        ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR}
)
add_definitions(-DNAPI_VERSION=3)
```